# php extract zip file in safe_mode on

Tags: php, ftp, extract

how can i do **extract zip** file for script setup in **safe_mode on**

i'm trying this

```
   require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
   $archive = new PclZip('archive.zip');
   if (($v_result_list = $archive->extract()) == 0) {
     die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
   }
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($v_result_list);
   echo "</pre>";
```

but i get OWNER error on the extracted dir

**How** do i fix this problem, or i think re connect to this ftp again and upload and extract file to this ftp

```
   $local_file = './arcive.zip';
   $ftp_path = '/extract';
   $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
   ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
   $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);
```

**How** do you think i can do?

Comment: how come not just use PHP's Zip feature? I'm sure it unzips as i've done it before using a zip file to hold profile templates. Unless it's different in safe_mode which i don't remember if was or not. Most likely was though.

Answer (score 1):

when a file is unzipped it preserves the owner and permissions information. In your case it's likely that the permissions do not allow world access. if the owner of the file is different from the account that PHP runs under, you cannot chown the file or change permissions. Unless PHP is run as root (and who does that?). in safe mode you can't even do that as root.
Ask the person who archives the file to make it "read & write" for everybody.

As for the second part of the question, you cannot extract something on another server over ftp protocol. you'd have to ssh into the server.
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net might be of help in that